# ELI5: How does converting an IEnumerable to a list or array avoid the performance penalty of multiple enumeration of IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, resharper, ienumerable, enumeration

Resharper constantly complains about this: *Possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable*. For example:

```
    private int ParseLoanNumber(IEnumerable<string> lines)
    {
        var loanNumber = 0;

        var item = lines.FirstOrDefault(l => l.StartsWith(" LN#    00"));

        if (item != null)
        {
            loanNumber = item.ParseInt(8, 10).GetValueOrDefault();
        }
        else
        {
            item = lines.FirstOrDefault(l => l.StartsWith(" LOAN-NO (CONT'D)  00"));
            if (item != null)
            {
                loanNumber = item.ParseInt(19, 10).GetValueOrDefault();
            }
        }
        // Yada yada...
    }
```

The recommended solution is to convert the `enumerable` to a `list` or `array`, and iterate over that.

This baffles me. You will still be enumerating something, and both types (arrays and lists) implement `IEnumerable`. So how does this solve anything, or improve performance in any way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you can write this:

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetNumbersSlowly()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000); //Or retrieve from a website, etc
        yield return i;
    }
}
```

If you use it like this:

```
var numbers = GetNumbersSlowly();
foreach(var number in numbers) { 
    //Do something 
}
foreach(var number in numbers) { 
    //Do something 
}
```

It means the work done (the sleep) is done *twice* for each number. Evaluating the enumerable once and storing it in an array or list means you're sure there's no extra processing being done to return the items.

Since you're taking an `IEnumerable<string>`, you really *don't know* that the caller hasn't done the above.

If you think my example might be rare or an edge case, it also applies to things like this:

```
var someSource = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var numbers = someSource.Select(s => s * 100000);
```

Now every time you iterate `numbers`, you're also re-doing the calculation. In this case it's not much work, by why do it more than you need (and it's not uncommon for it to be non-trivial work).

Comment: Just to give other examples; some `IEnumerable<T>` are simply not repeatable - for example, they can be drawing data from a `Socket` or an external source like a database query wrapping an `IDataReader` ("dapper" allows this type of usage, for example), or they could be pulling numbers from a PRNG, etc

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, the performance penalty from not converting comes from *deferred execution*. Is that approximately correct?